# Why can I not delete a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a button that calls a function to delete a cookie and reload the page.
The issue is that the cookie will not delete.  I've read dozens of tutorials and examples online and I don't understand why the cookie will not delete.

Here is the simple code:

```
function logMeOut() {
    document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;"; 
    alert(document.cookie);
    location.reload();
}
```

The alert pops up and reads `username=knrast`

Why is the alert reading out the cookie when I just deleted it on the previous line of code?

Comment: I believe so? Although to be quite honest I'm not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: What is the _path_ of the cookie you're trying to delete? Also, "logging out" clientside like this will not end the session (if any) on the server-side. If you just want to store data on the client side look into **[_localStorage_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

Comment: @PaulS.  Thank you! The issue was the path was not the same so that's why it did not delete the cookie. The Path of the cookie was "www.domain.com/this" and the path where the code is executed is on "www.domain.com/this/that"  After specifying the path the code now deletes the cookie!

Comment: The path and domain need to be the same as the original if you want to "delete" it

Comment: @Konrad you may want to read this, for a better idea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the path was not the same so that's why it did not delete the cookie. The Path of the cookie was "www.domain.com/this" and the path where the code is executed is on "www.domain.com/this/that" After specifying the path the code now deletes the cookie!

New code

```
document.cookie = "username=; path=/this/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;";
```

This is now working!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" error comes up when I try @keizom

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine. My test:

```
document.cookie = "username=test; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:01 UTC;";
console.log('"' + document.cookie + '"');
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;";
console.log('"' + document.cookie + '"');
```

Prints:

```
"username=test"
""
```

Maybe it's related to your `alert`?